# The amount you can adjust a Chinese characters look without it changing meaning

Tags: characters, fonts

I'm wondering how much freedom a designer has of a Chinese character, if they must make every stroke exactly in the correct position and thickness and direction and shape and everything, or if they can have some freedom in where it's placed, its orientation, emphasis/focusability in the context of the whole character, etc.

I would like to know how much creative freedom you have in designing a custom look and feel for a Chinese character.

I'm looking at for example the variation in styles [here](https://www.freechinesefont.com/category/modern/page/3/), but other than thickness of the character strokes they all look pretty similar. You don't see highly custom designs like you do with the Latin alphabet, which is the reason for the question. Even [this modern sans-serif font looks similar to the others](https://www.monotype.com/resources/font-stories/a-digital-ready-chinese-sans-serif-is-born/). [This](https://www.hackingchinese.com/handwriting-chinese-characters-the-minimum-requirements/) was helpful.

Comment: http://m.fonts.net.cn/fonts-zh-3.html there are many creative fonts you can make comparison XD

Comment: https://www.qt86.com/

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a lot of styles when it comes to handwriting.  You can check out this page https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E4%B9%A6%E6%B3%95. It can be quite hard to understand sometimes. like this one https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8D%89%E4%B9%A6 .